# Having trouble referencing elements in my styling sheet

Tags: html, css, user-interface, model-view-controller

I'm trying to style my unordered list, but I can't seem to reference the items in my CSS. I've tried referencing the class name, and referencing the element by doing ul li i, using #divname, etc. Right now I'm simply styling the list directly in the HTML page, but it looks horrible.

I can't seem to reference theses html elements in my CSS - how can I properly reference these elements in my CSS? more importantly I'd like to understand how to know what to write down in my styling sheets so I can understand the concept.

Here's my html:

```html
  <div class="navbar-container">
                    <ul class="navbar-items" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: 57%; margin-top: 11px;">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" style="text-decoration:none; color: #333333;" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" style="text-decoration:none; color: #333333;" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" style="text-decoration:none; color: #333333;" asp-area="" asp-controller="Course" asp-action="Index">Courses</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" style="text-decoration:none; color: #333333;" asp-area="" asp-controller="Professor" asp-action="Index">Professors</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: Is the problem tied specifically to the unordered list? or do the other css customizations also not taking effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have an example of your CSS code? Link it with the following in the head section of the html;

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="#">
```

You can select them with the following;

```
.navbar-container {} 
ul {}
.navbar-items {} 
.nav-items {}
li {}
.nav-link {}
.text-dark {}
```

Then the following;

```
.nav-item {
  color: blue;
}

.nav-item:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: I didn't add my CSS because it literally doesn't do anything since I can't access any of the elements. When I try styling my links with .nav-link:hover i cant get the hover color to change, despite my code changing the color. It doesn't show up in the browser. other elements like body work but i cant access the ones for the UL

Comment: It's because your in-line HTML styles are taking priority. Create a stylesheet and remove the in-line styles, then use the following;